# Perl: enforce inheritance of modules

Tags: perl, inheritance

I have a Perl package (e.g. car) that is meant to be a base class of some other modules (e.g. van, limousine, convertible, ...) -

```
use base ("car");
```

in the pm-file of van, ...

I need to make sure car is not used - only the use of the inherited objects (van, limo, ...) is allowed.

Today I do it if ref () inside the base-class. If it returns the name of "car" I know it is used without inheritance and then I quit with an error.

If van, ... is used ref () would return "van", ...

Is there a more elegant/static way to do that. Lets say a way I can get a sort of syntax-error??

And no: I do not like to discuss the weakness of Perl in OO-topics compared to OO-languages ;-)

**edit:**
Here is a sample. It works.

The question is if the is a more better way to do the check in car::new.

```
#---------car.pm----------
package car;

sub new
{ 
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {};
  bless ($self, $class);

  if(ref($self) eq "car")    # thats my check to make sure beep exists
  { die "no allowed because no beep here"; 
  }

  $return $self;
}

sub honk
{ beep ();    # only defined in the inherited class (van, ...)
}

1;


#----van.pm-----
package van;

use car;
use base ("car");

sub beep 
{
   print "tuuuut";
}
1;

#---------main.pl---------
car->new ()->honk ();   # dies
# if no ref-check it would crush because no beep in car.

van->new ()->honk ();   # ok but maybe not most elegant
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you at least [edit] and include an example of what you are doing now, and maybe a bit more explanation of why you don't like that.

Comment: @simbabque: I think he's trying to write a virtual base class (aka an abstract class). Schwern's [Class::Virtual](https://metacpan.org/release/Class-Virtual) might have some useful ideas.

Comment: @DaveCross Club Sandwich.

Comment: I will edit and put a small sample in.

Comment: Oh. I thought when you said _used_ you meant _`use`d_. [ysth's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39899754/1331451) makes sense then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't show your code, but it sounds like you aren't checking in the right place; you should only need to do this in the constructor:

```
sub new {
    my ($class, @other_args) = @_;
    if ($class eq __PACKAGE__) {
        Carp::croak "must be subclassed";
    }
```

But no, there isn't a way to do it at compile time.

Comment: This assumes that none of the subclasses completely override the constructor. That's unlikely, but not impossible.

Comment: @DaveCross If they override the constructor, they are a subclass and there is no problem.

Comment: D'oh! Yes. I'm feeling particularly stupid today :-/

Comment: I put a sample in my question. Is __PACKAGE__ better than ref?

Comment: It's better in the sense that it works, while there's nothing on which to call `ref`.

Comment: @chris: This code short-circuits sooner than your version does. It avoids the need to create an object before checking the class. It checks the class that the object would be, and dies if you're about to create an object of the abstract class.